# Spring security returns String as principal instead of UserDetails on failed login?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Either I'm missing something, or this is how it works...
Namely, I implemented `UserDetailsService`, and sub-classed (`AppUser` below) spring utility class `User`, (that implements `UserDetails`). If it matters, it goes something like this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // try loading user by its name
    SystemUser user = null;
    try {
        user = this.sysUserService.getByUsername(username);
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new DataRetrievalFailureException(
                "Could not load user with username: " + username);
    }
    // load user rights, and create UserDetails instance
    UserDetails res = new AppUser(user, getUserAuthorities(user));

    return res;
}
```

Then I tried to implement account locking using this approach:

```
public class LoginFailureEventListenter implements
ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

// rest omitted for brevity

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
    // ...

    SystemUser user = ((AppUser)event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getSystemUser();
    // cast exception - how is it possible to obtain String 
    // instead of UserDetails object here ?
    // ...
}
}
```

However, I ran into `java.lang.ClassCastException` while trying to get the principal object from the supplied event argument (principal object was of type `String`). I mean, OK - I can just load my `SystemUser` by username again, to solve the problem, but I did not expect this...
I think that even the source documentation states that `getPrincipal()` should return `UserDetails` instance, for this scenario.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we are dealing with an authentication failure, the `Authentication` object in the event is the one which was submitted to the `AuthenticationManager` (and which was rejected).

In a typical scenario this would be a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` where the "principal" property is the submitted username.

The `AuthenticationManager` supports lots of different authentication mechanisms and, from its perspective, there's no guarantee that a `UserDetailsService` is even involved in the authentication. All it knows is that the authentication token was not accepted (there was an exception) and it publishes the event accordingly.

Alternative options are to customize the `AuthenticationProvider` in use or plug in an `AuthenticationFailureHandler` (if you're using form-login, for example) and do the extra work in there.

Comment: So, this is actually the way it's supposed to be...?  I'm already using `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for counter reset, cant tell if this is the right approach, it did not occur to me to try with `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to be. The event says "this is the authentication request which failed", and the authentication request only contains a string identifier for the user.