# Spring Security getprincipal() method returns string (Username) in place of class UserDetails

Tags: linux, spring-boot, jwt, war, spring-security-oauth2

We are using Spring-boot 2.0.5 with JWT Token

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`   returning `String (Username)` in place of `CustomUserDetails` Object which is implemented `UserDetails` class  in WAR file only.

This issue only replicates occasionally  most of the time the code is working perfectly

The below mention is the only custom filter we are using and it is called after FilterSecurityInterceptor Filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper request = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) req);
    if(request!=null && request.getHeader("Authorization")!=null && request.getHeader("Authorization").length()>7) {

        CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
}
```

It should be returning user detail object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring security returns String as principal instead of UserDetails on failed login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453200/spring-security-returns-string-as-principal-instead-of-userdetails-on-failed-log)

Comment: It depends on configuration, in our case we were using DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter in AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer and it relies on UserDetailsService for getting the UserDetails if it is not set you will get a string i.e. username instead of UserDetail object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in our case, there were two Bean with the same name  which was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to provide you any answers, it will be good to know:

- what instance returns from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`?
- what is list of security filters you have and where is your custom one located?
- when does this happen? you must to know steps to reproduce it

Comment: what instance returns from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()?
-----it return SecurityContext
what is list of security filters you have and where is your custom one located?
-----Custom security filter is only filter as mention above   
-----it is executed after FilterSecurityInterceptor
when does this happen? you must to know steps to reproduce it
----- whenever tried to call a authorize endpoint

Comment: re #1 SecurityContext comes from getContext() but what instance of Authentication is?

Comment: re #2 can you share some logic from your custom filter?